# Extra space while selecting text using Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem while attempting to select text using Google Chrome. There is always extra space selected along with the text. This behaviour is illustrated in the following images between Google Chrome and Internet Explorer:

Google Chrome:

[image]

Internet Explorer:

[image]

So out of the two browsers, only Google Chrome have the problem but the IE does not. Microsoft Edge and Firefox too does not have the problem either. On the other hand, Opera does have the problem so apparently all browsers built using Chromium may have the problem. Is there a workaround until the problem is fixed from the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour appeared to be a bug in Blink (the chromium engine) and it just got fixed recently. Latest Chromium builds have this bug fixed already. In addition, both Chrome Canary and Chrome beta (47.0.2526.27) does not have the bug either which means Chrome adapted the fixed version of Chromium in dev builds at least from (47.0.2526.27).

[Screenshot of selecting the same content in question using Chrome beta (47.0.2526.27)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orP3m.png)

The latest Chrome Stable (at the time or writing this) is (46.0.2490.71) does STILL have the bug so it is a matter of time until it gets updated. Opera will have the bug fixed as will in later builds.